# Simple join calculation of dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `a`, with A, B, C are separate entries

```
Source Target N
A B 100
A D 200
```

I have another dataframe `b` for entries' attributes

```
Name Rate1 Rate2
A  0.1 0.2
B  0.2 0.3
```

I want to calculate a new column `Flow`  in `a`, as it is calculated row based by `Flow = a$N * b[Name == a$Source]$Rate1`. I tried to use `apply` by row, but I felt it's slow. Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a fairly expressive solution, fairly similar to the code you tried:

```
>  a$Flow <- a$N*b$Rate1[ match(a$Source, b$Name) ]
> a
  Source Target   N Flow
1      A      B 100   10
2      A      D 200   20
```

The `match` function is the basis for `merge` and `%in%`. It is particularly useful for constructing index vectors to pick from alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what you have tried with apply, but here an answer with merge and transform

```
  transform(merge(a,b,by.x = 'Source',by.y ='Name'),flow = N*Rate1)

  Source Target   N Rate1 Rate2 flow
1      A      B 100   0.1   0.2   10
2      A      D 200   0.1   0.2   20
```